# CMake error: log4cppD not found in package?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, target, conan

I got an error in CLion caused by CMake. It says that Cmake cannot find the log4cppD package.

Here is a piece of the conanfile.py

```
def package_info(self):
    self.cpp_info.set_property("cmake_find_mode", "both")
    if self.settings.build_type == "Debug":
      self.cpp_info.libs = ["log4cppD"]
    else:
      self.cpp_info.libs = ["log4cpp"]
    if self.settings.os == "Linux":
      self.cpp_info.system_libs.append("pthread")
```

And this is the CMake error:

```
CMake Error at cmakedeps_macros.cmake:67 (message):
  Library 'log4cppD' not found in package.  If 'log4cppD' is a system
  library, declare it with 'cpp_info.system_libs' property
```

Please help me, I am confused

Comment: But do you actually have this library in your system? Maybe only `log4cpp` but not `log4cppD` ?

Comment: log4cppD is only a debug convention, so the actual lib is log4cpp

Comment: Nope, it's not "only" a debug convention. This convention affects the actual libraries filenames that are looked for, so if you didn't build your log4cplus with the same convention (adding 'D' at the end), then it will not be found. So, do you have requested libraries in the path where cmake is supposed to look for them?

Comment: Thank you very much. In my conanfile.py I am adding the dependencies for log4cpp but not log4cpp, so your approach is that i change it to log4cppD?

Comment: That's only to answer your question about "CMake cannot find the log4cppD". How you should configure your conan project is another topic. Best would be to follow [one of those](https://docs.conan.io/1/creating_packages/package_approaches.html) conan tutorials from official docs. You will see there that normally you just define the dependency once `self.cpp_info.libs = ["log4cpp"]` and then it's up to conan to figure out the library full name. But it's a longer topic, not fit for StackOverflow Q/A format.

Comment: The ``package_info()`` you are writing there is for the ``log4cpp`` package, I understand that you are creating that package yourself? If you are creating the package, you have control over the library names, and they should match, but it seems they are not matching?

Comment: Assuming it's this library: https://sourceforge.net/p/log4cpp/codegit/ci/master/tree/CMakeLists.txt#l13, you may want to patch their CMakeLists in order to add cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15) before project(), otherwise it may defeat CMakeToolchain generator. Except of that, are you sure that you have built Debug log4cpp and are configuring your own project with CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug?